# kafka confluent error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/confluent.PVghAKRg/zookeeper/data/myid file is missing

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am running Kafka via a Confluent platform on 3 nodes but when i running `confluent start` get this error :

```
[2018-04-09 10:54:25,995] INFO Reading configuration from: /tmp/confluent.SVNfiLFU/zookeeper/zookeeper.properties (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-04-09 10:54:26,011] INFO Resolved hostname: 0.0.0.0 to address: /0.0.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2018-04-09 10:54:26,011] INFO Resolved hostname: 192.168.0.36 to address: /192.168.0.36 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2018-04-09 10:54:26,011] INFO Resolved hostname: 192.168.0.22 to address: /192.168.0.22 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
[2018-04-09 10:54:26,011] INFO Defaulting to majority quorums (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig)
[2018-04-09 10:54:26,012] ERROR Invalid config, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain)
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /tmp/confluent.SVNfiLFU/zookeeper/zookeeper.properties
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:154)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:101)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /tmp/confluent.SVNfiLFU/zookeeper/data/myid file is missing
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:406)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:150)
        ... 2 more
```

this is zookeeper.properties :

```
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
tickTime=2000

server.1=192.168.0.21:2888:3888
server.2=192.168.0.22:2888:3888
server.3=192.168.0.36:2888:3888
```

also, I created `myid` file that contains integer id in `/var/lib/zookeeper/` directory

Comment: Did you happen to reboot your computer? Why are you storing data in /tmp?

Comment: I define the directory to `var/lib/zookeeper` but confluent overwrite my config.
I think `Confluent CLI ` does not support clustering

Comment: That's very correct. It only is for localhost testing. I'm fairly sure the documentation specifically states this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `zookeeper-server-start.sh zookeeper.properties` individual on each server.

[`confluent` command is only for single node testing](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html#cli) (emphasis added)

> meant for development purposes only and is not suitable for a production environment. The data that are produced are **transient and are intended to be temporary**

That explains why you're getting errors about files in /tmp